# Which non-homogeneous scalar manifolds are possible in supergravity?

Tags: mathematical-physics, supersymmetry, supergravity

The scalar fields in various supergravity theories are restricted (by supersymmetry) to span the target (scalar) manifolds of a certain class (e.g. Hodge-Kahler, quaternion-Kahler etc.), depending on the spacetime dimension and the amount of supersymmetry.

The scalar manifolds which appear in the literature are usually homogeneous. However, it seems that they can just as well be non-homogeneous, while still lying in a class imposed by supersymmetry. I wonder if there are any constraints on the non-homogeneous deformations which are allowed with the original supersymmetry kept intact. I'm interested in any dimension/amount of supersymmetry where the scalar manifolds are not completely fixed and such deformations are thus allowed.